# Joining sublists in two nested in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-series, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I am sorry for the long post. Please could someone help me with the merging of two nested lists of different lengths?  There are countless examples of joining lists "elementwise" on Google and on SO, but none of them seem to cover my case exactly.  I need to do this thousands of times, on lists which are ~1 million lines long each.

One list has the format:

```
shortdata = [
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:02","1.21034","1.21039","1.21038","1.21037"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:04","1.21032","1.21035","1.21034","1.21034"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:06","1.21021","1.21027","1.21028","1.21028"],
...
["2015.01.01 22:00:56","1.21040","1.21038","1.21039","1.21039"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:58","1.21041","1.21042","1.21047","1.21050"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:02","1.21047","1.21033","1.21035","1.21035"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:04","1.21045","1.21034","1.21036","1.21032"],
...
]
```

The other list has the format:

```
longdata = [
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
...
]
```

I would like to join the sublists together so that the output is a list of the combined sublists, possibly with some padding of empty columns, i.e. something like:

```
combineddata = [
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:00:02","1.21034","1.21039","1.21038","1.21037"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:00:04","1.21032","1.21035","1.21034","1.21034"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:00:06","1.21021","1.21027","1.21028","1.21028"],
...
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:00:56","1.21040","1.21038","1.21039","1.21039"],
["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038", "", "",["2015.01.01 22:00:58","1.21041","1.21042","1.21047","1.21050"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035", "","", "2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:01:02","1.21047","1.21033","1.21035","1.21035"],
["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035", "", "", "2015.01.01 22:01:04","1.21045","1.21034","1.21036","1.21032"],
...
]
```

The 'minute data' is repeated on each row purposefully because it is needed for row-by-row calculations.

If I do a straight list comprehension it doesn't work because the lists are different lengths - there is obviously far more 2sec data than 1minute data.

I then thought that I could duplicate the elements of the 1-minute data to make it the same length as the 2s data so that then I could just zip the two lists together.  This also failed spectacularly:

```
expandedlist = [[x] * n for x in longdata]
```

but I end up with an incorrect format, e.g. for n = 3 for demonstration (rather than 30!):

```
[[['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']], [['2015.01.01 22:01:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037'], ['2015.01.01 22:01:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037'], ['2015.01.01 22:01:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037']], 
...
```

So there is a bit too much nesting.  Ive tried removing the outer '[]' signs, trying list(x) instead of [x], and using outer brackets '(', none of which result in something that is in the intended format to be zipped with the 2s data.

I thought perhaps I could use itertools.izip_longest() with a fillvalue and make it 'fill' the 2s rows with the required one-minute data, something like:

```
combinedlist = list(itertools.izip_longest(longdata, shortdata, fillvalue=<something goes here>))
print combinedlist
```

I don't really understand the syntax and even filling the filevalue with a simple string shows that it doesn't look much like the intended output.  I get:

```
[(['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:01:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:02', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:02:00', '1.2105', '1.2105', '1.2105', '1.2105'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:04', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:03:00', '1.21043', '1.21043', '1.21043', '1.21043'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:06', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:04:00', '1.21049', '1.21049', '1.21049', '1.21049'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:08', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:05:00', '1.21043', '1.21043', '1.21038', '1.21038'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:10', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:06:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:12', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:07:00', '1.21041', '1.21041', '1.21041', '1.21041'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:14', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), (['2015.01.01 22:08:00', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037', '1.21037'], ['2015.01.01 22:00:16', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), ('foo', ['2015.01.01 22:00:18', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), ('foo', ['2015.01.01 22:00:20', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038', '1.21038']), ('foo',...
```

Finally, I thought that I could put all of the 1-minute data in a dictionary, and then look up the left-most 17 characters of the 2s timestamp (e.g. "2015.01.01 22:00:") in the dictionary to do the join, but this seems somewhat cumbersome (?).

I've also considered a bisect method (i.e. to bisect the minute data every time I reach a ":00" in the 2s data time stamps, but I am not sure this will be the fastest way either.

What would be the most fastest (or most elegant) way to do what I am attempting to do, or do I need to write out a full loop to join the lists together?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep a position in the minute data (starting with 0) while iterating through the second data.  Every time I see a minute increment in the second data, I would increase that position in the minute data.  Then I would `yield` the elements as wished:

```
shortdata = [
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:02","1.21034","1.21039","1.21038","1.21037"],
  # ...
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:58","1.21041","1.21042","1.21047","1.21050"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:02","1.21047","1.21033","1.21035","1.21035"],
  # ...
]

longdata = [
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
  # ...
]

def each_mixed_line(sh, lo):
  lo_pos = 0
  for sh_line in sh:
    while lo_pos < len(lo)-1 and lo[lo_pos+1][0] <= sh_line[0]:
      lo_pos += 1
    yield lo[lo_pos] + [ '', '' ] + sh_line

for mixed_line in each_mixed_line(shortdata, longdata):
  print(mixed_line)
```

In many cases you do not need to build the complete resulting list but instead can step through it like shown with the `print()`.  This is way less memory consuming and thus recommended.  But if you need to build the resulting list, you can just do it:

```
combineddata = list(each_mixed_line(shortdata, longdata))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alfe - such a neat solution!  If you don't mind, Im going to take some time to 'play' with the code and make sure I understand it before I "accept" your answer.  Presumably I will need to convert the datetime stamps using strptime to make the datetime comparison work as intended?  Thank you once again!

Comment: Take your time.  Well, I assumed your timestamps are the way they are presented here, so they can be compared simply using `<` etc.  If you indeed have something more complex like `Tue Apr 17 16:46:34 2018` then you will have to parse them all and convert them into sth like *seconds since 1970* to allow comparing them.

Comment: Hi Alfe, I tested your solution and that of @appleapple yesterday on a 'full set' of data and did some speed tests.  I was a little surprised to see that your code is actually faster - for some reason I had assumed that his code would run quicker.  In any case, both are great solutions to my problem, with yours being faster and his possibly being a little neater (?).  I really wish I could accept both answers and Im so grateful for your help.  I'll accept your answer on the basis that it was fastest and you got there first, and hopefully it wont cause any offence!  Thank you again!

Comment: The main difference between our versions is that mine does not assume a fixed number (30) of seconds values for each minutes value.  So if there is a seconds entry skipped in your data (that might happen) apple-apple's solution will mix them wrong.  This behavior is called *brittle*, and mine is more *robust*.  But actually maybe you are sure in your case that the input behaves neatly and does never skip anything, so this aspect might be of minor importance to you.

Answer (score 1):

if your short and long list have `n times longer` relation (the `n` would be 30 in your example)

i.e `longtdata: [[1],[2]], shortdata: [[1.1],[1.2]...[1.n],[2.1],[2.2],...,[2.n],[3.1]...]`

then you can expend the short data by

```
expended_data = (x for l in longtdata for x in [l]*n)
```

or

```
expended_data = (x for l in longtdata for i in range(n))
```

and the `combineddata` becomes

```
combineddata = [a+["",""]+b for a,b in zip(expended_data,shortdata)]
```

Comment: Thanks appleapple I had to adapt your code slightly - I wonder if you meant `expandeddata = (x for s in longdata for x in [s]*n)` which then works perfectly with your `combineddata` line?  The code works perfectly but I am still speed-testing against @Alfe solution.  As a side query, if I try to print the `expandeddata` using the command line, the interpreter says `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fce730f1eb0>` if I wanted to "see" the expanded list before it is merged, what would I need to do?

Comment: @Paul use a generator takes less memory since it generate data on the fly. You can expend a generator simply use `list(expended_data)`. note that if you change it to `expended_data = [x for s in shortdata for x in [s]*n]` it's now a list.

Comment: @Paul and yes, I mix up `shortdata` and `longdata`. when I wrote this answer. I thought it meas *short list*, but it means *short period*. I would update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to change your `longdata` variable, you may simply extend each item with the corresponding items of `shortdata`, which is more efficient, as it allocates a minimum of new data. Here is the code:

```
shortdata = [
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:02","1.21034","1.21039","1.21038","1.21037"],
  # ...
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:58","1.21041","1.21042","1.21047","1.21050"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:02","1.21047","1.21033","1.21035","1.21035"],
  # ...
]

longdata = [
  ["2015.01.01 22:00:00","1.21036","1.21032","1.21033","1.21038"],
  ["2015.01.01 22:01:00","1.21044","1.21032","1.21033","1.21035"],
  # ...
]

n = 0
end = len(shortdata)
for long in longdata:
   prefix = long[0][:16]  # keep only significant part
   long.clear()           # because the first line of 'short' is same as 'long'
   while n < end:
     short = shortdata[n]
     if short[0][:16] != prefix: break
     long.extend(short + ['/'])
     n += 1
print(longdata)
```

Result:

```
[['2015.01.01 22:00:00', '1.21036', '1.21032', '1.21033', '1.21038', '/', 
  '2015.01.01 22:00:02', '1.21034', '1.21039', '1.21038', '1.21037', '/',
  ... 
  '2015.01.01 22:00:58', '1.21041', '1.21042', '1.21047', '1.21050', '/'], 
 ['2015.01.01 22:01:00', '1.21044', '1.21032', '1.21033', '1.21035', '/', 
  '2015.01.01 22:01:02', '1.21047', '1.21033', '1.21035', '1.21035', '/',
  ...
  '2015.01.01 22:01:58', '1.21041', '1.21042', '1.21047', '1.21050', '/'],
 ...
]
```

You may also replace the inner `while` by an iterator on `shortdata` but I'm not sure that it really speeds up the code. Need to time it...

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is *not* a concern, you can use a nested `for` loop. Note this is an O(n^2) solution.

The benefit is that the logic is more closely aligned with the data: you are using `datetime` objects and checking explicitly whether the long_date <= short_date < long_date + 1 minute.

```
from  datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = defaultdict(list)
td = timedelta(0, 60)
res = []

for short in shortdata:
    s_date = datetime.strptime(short[0], '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
    for long in longdata:
        l_date = datetime.strptime(long[0], '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S')
        if l_date <= s_date < l_date + td:
            res.append(long + short)
```